# How to get a list of all document types

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I use `elesticserach_dsl` in `Python` to do searching, and I really like it. But the thing I do not know how to impement, is how to get a list of all different document types. The catch is `type` field plays for me almost the same role as table name in `SQL`, and what I want to do, is to somehow mimic `SHOW TABLES` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do this in Python, but from Elasticsearch point of view, this is how the request looks like:

```
GET /_all/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_type",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've just read something about this (aggregations) and it looks promissing.